# Plotly scatter_mapbox not resizing bubbles size when filter using Dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, mapbox-marker, jupyterdash

I'm trying to create some charts using Dash. The first one is a map chart about crimes in a specific town, using latitude and longitude to put a bubble in the chart, and the size of the bubble is how many times that crime happened in the same latitude and longitude.

code:

```
app = JupyterDash(__name__)

# assume you have a "long-form" data frame
# see https://plotly.com/python/px-arguments/ for more options



app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='graph-with-slider'),
    dcc.Slider(
        dfAgg['year'].min(),
        dfAgg['year'].max(),
        step=None,
        value=dfAgg['year'].min(),
        marks={str(year): str(year) for year in dfAgg['year'].unique()},
        id='year-slider'
    )
])


@app.callback(
    Output('graph-with-slider', 'figure'),
    Input('year-slider', 'value'))
def update_figure(selected_year):
    filtered_df = dfAgg[dfAgg.year == selected_year]

    fig = px.scatter_mapbox(filtered_df, lat="y", lon="x",color = 'category', size='counts',hover_name="category", size_max=70, zoom=12)
    fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")

    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(mode='inline')
```

I tried to do a filter by year in the chart and everything but the size of the bubbles and the colors are working great. After I change the years there aren't any alterations in the bubble size and color, although it changes the size value.

[chart 2020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXYNE.png)

[chart 2021](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15MkV.png)

```
Sample =

{'x': {13095: -82.98688222511271,
  14604: -82.97422429540345,
  6832: -83.02918556510366,
  6732: -83.02979740652734,
  16371: -82.95080057568634,
  9559: -83.01477492317612,
  8971: -83.01798012419118,
  7791: -83.02472262154369,
  3443: -83.05091953723883,
  6123: -83.03297734211543},
 'y': {13095: 42.320637428464366,
  14604: 42.30702343574098,
  6832: 42.31687045400542,
  6732: 42.303062978388915,
  16371: 42.2953748340745,
  9559: 42.32349164014955,
  8971: 42.32087765724121,
  7791: 42.31846232005631,
  3443: 42.31429527361399,
  6123: 42.31855936386481},
 'year': {13095: 2021,
  14604: 2020,
  6832: 2022,
  6732: 2021,
  16371: 2021,
  9559: 2022,
  8971: 2022,
  7791: 2022,
  3443: 2021,
  6123: 2021},
 'category': {13095: 'Fraud',
  14604: 'Break and Enter',
  6832: 'Robbery',
  6732: 'Theft',
  16371: 'Theft',
  9559: 'Break and Enter',
  8971: 'Traffic',
  7791: 'Fraud',
  3443: 'Theft',
  6123: 'Theft'},
 'counts': {13095: 1,
  14604: 1,
  6832: 1,
  6732: 5,
  16371: 7,
  9559: 1,
  8971: 2,
  7791: 2,
  3443: 1,
  6123: 6}}
```

Comment: Since no data is presented, I am guessing. I think the fact that you are specifying size in the scatterplot specification is limiting the size and the colors linked to it.

Comment: There is just a few bubbles with more than 70 in size, the majority of them have between 1 and 4. I tried change the size_max too and nothing happened.

Comment: @GiovanniRiccardiLourenzatto can you include a small subset of your data so we can try to reproduce the behavior? you can copy and paste the output from `dfAgg.head(10).to_dict()` directly into the question.

Comment: Hi @DerekO, I placed in the question. Probably will need to duplicate some data to make the bubble size bigger.